# How can I customize Eclipse's getter and setter generation?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I configure Eclipse to generate getters and setters with some prefix for argument variable?

Example:

```
private String someVariable;

public void setSomeVariable(String aSomeVariable) {
    this.someVariable = aSomeVariable;
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Jay - to avoid the parameter hiding the field of the same name.  An easy bug can be introduced if more code is added to setSomeVariable and you reference the parameter when you meant the field or vice-versa.

Answer (score 21):

You can update all generated variables with a prefix by going to preferences > java > Code Style and selecting Parameters then edit.  You can add a prefix/suffix for all generated variable names.

Comment: Wow, really didn't know this. I had to do it the other way around since my getters and setters were generated preficed with `p`.

Answer (score 5):

there are two thing that you need to do to effect the setter in your example.
first, as others have mentioned, you will need to go to the Preferences dialog and go to Java/Code Style/Code Templates/Code/Setter body.  in the Pattern box, you should make the value to look like this:

`this.${field} = ${param};`

second, still in the Preferences dialog, go up a level to Code Style.  Here you will see a table 'Conventions for variable names.'  Select the Parameters row and select edit.  add the letter `a` to the prefix field.

Once all of that is saved, you should be able to automatically generate setters as you have defined above, using the Generate Getter and Setter" command.

Comment: which version of eclipse you refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Right click -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters -> Click on the Code Template link just above the OK button -> Code

I usually write my setter like:
if (${param}!=null)
    ${field} = ${param};
else 
return new String();

Answer (score 0):

You can select the variable(s) and right click > source > Generate getters and setters.  If you only want setters uncheck the getVariable() option.

Comment: yes, but in addition he wants to customize the name of the setters' argument.