# How to force Eclipse to use the this keyword when auto-generating getters and setters?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, this

In Eclipse, is there a way to force the use of the `this` keyword with referring to class members when auto-generating getters and setters?

For example, I want this getter, auto-generated by Eclipse,

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

to be rewritten with

```
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Is that possibe? If yes, how?

### ANSWER:

(The answer is provided by [Vitaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236253/vitaly), but to make things clear:)

In the top menu, click **Window > Preferences**.
Then, in the **Preferences** window, click **Java  > Code Style**
You'll see a checkbox with *Qualify all generated field accesses with 'this.'* Tick this checkbox.

Works like a charm.

(Notice that `'this.'` must be `'this'.`.)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/977983/235710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open  `Source -> Generate Getters and Setters`

There is a link at the botton to `Code Templates`, click it.

Choose - will you change project settings or workspace settings.

In `Configure generated code and comments`, expand `Code` and select `Getter Body`, in pattern add `this.`.

That's it.

Note: You can open `Code Templates` from project properties or from workspace preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your code template under window->preferences.  There are a couple of different pages that have code templates.  You'll find the getters and setters in one of them.

Or when you generate getters and setters from the source menu, the dialog has a link to the code templates that you can click.

Answer (score 0):

Vitalay's approach works, but there is an easier and better all-around option now. Here's the newer approach:

1. Window->Preferences
2. Search 'Code Style'
3. Check the box for 'Qualify all generated field accesses with 'this.'

If you use the old approach you'd have to repeat the process for each section, whereas this checkbox applies to all generated code (ex: getters, setters, constructors, implemented methods).